# Covariant derivative along higher order tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, lie-derivative

I've recently started to review some Riemann calculus and I've got a question that I could not find anywhere else. So, the covariant derivative along a vector field is defined as:
\begin{equation}
 \nabla_{\vec{v}}=v^{i}\nabla_{\vec{e}_{i}}
\end{equation}
So far, so good. My question is how can we define a covariant derivative along a rank-2 tensor, i.e., what is the definition of:
\begin{equation}
  \nabla_{T}=T^{ij}\nabla_{\vec{e}_i\vec{e}_j} \quad,\quad \nabla_{\vec{e}_i\vec{e}_j}=?
\end{equation}

Comment: Never heard of such things. Any reason(s) to think about that?

Comment: Well, normally the covariant derivative is defined along vector field. So, why does one not define a covariant derivative along a rank-2 tensor? Geometrically, it can means how a vector field, for example, changes in relation to a rank-2 tensor. But how is it defined?

Comment: The Covariant derivative isn't a derivative of a tensor w.r.t. a vector, so much as a *directional derivative* of a tensor. Higher order tensors don't correspond to "directions" in the same way. The most obvious generalization would be the $k$-th order covariant derivative $\nabla_{v_1}\dots\nabla_{v_k}T$ which is taken with respect to $k$ vectors, or equivalently a single $k$-tensor.

Comment: Note you don't need a vector _field_ in that slot of the covariant derivative, just a single vector.